# PHP Regex help needed

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable like below in PHP.

```
$content = 'abc def <img src="https://www.example.com/images/abc.png" /> end';
```

I have to use regex to remove everything except img src. So the final value:

```
$content = 'https://www.example.com/images/abc.png';
```

I have regex in java to do it but I have to do it in PHP and I am not able to do it.

Java Code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]*src=[\\\"']([^\\\"^']*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
while (m.find()) {
    String src = m.group();
    int startIndex = src.indexOf("src=") + 5;
    content = src.substring(startIndex, src.length());
    break; // break after first image is found
}
```

How do I do it, I am novice in PHP and struggling here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are almost there. If just need the first image, as indicated by your code you could use `preg_match()` like that:

```
<?php
$re = '/<img[^>]*src=[\\\"\']([^\\\"^\']*)/i';
$str = 'abc def <img src="https://www.example.com/images/abc.png" /> end';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE4BkV/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you can choose, avoid using regular expressions to parse HTML data. An HTML parser is safer in this case:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$srcs = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $imgs->length; ++$i) {
    $srcs[] = $imgs->item($i)->getAttribute('src');
}
```

If you are sure that one and only one `img` tag exists, you can proceed as follows:

```
// ...
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: Thanks but my requirement is very simple and I don't want to load whole HTML because it might be an invalid HTML too. But your code is very good and I will use it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same in PHP.
I generated the code with [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

```
$re = '/<img[^>]*src=[\\\\\"\']([^\\\\\"^\']*)/';
$str = 'abc def <img src="https://www.example.com/images/abc.png" /> end';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```